# Generar row number de tabla sql con Criteria en java

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Anteriormente en el proyecto en el que estoy una consulta sql daba una respuesta asi:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      rownumber() over(
        order by 
          this_.FECHA desc, 
          this_.NUMERO_ACTIVIDAD desc
      ) as rownumber_, 
      this_.ID_ACTIVIDAD as y0_, 
      motivocont3_.DESCRIPCION as y1_, 
      this_.FECHA as y2_, 
      this_.HORA as y3_, 
      estado2_.DESCRIPCION as y4_, 
      formaconta4_.DESCRIPCION as y5_, 
      clasificac5_.DESCRIPCION as y6_, 
      this_.USUARIO_CREADOR as y7_, 
      this_.NOMBRE_SUJ_ACT as y8_, 
      this_.ID_ACTIVIDAD_EXTERNA as y9_, 
      this_.NUMERO_ACTIVIDAD as y10_, 
      this_.PERSONA_CONTACTO as y11_, 
      this_.NOMBRE_SUJ_CONT as y12_, 
      this_.NUMERO_CONTACTO as y13_, 
      this_.ANI as y14_, 
      this_.ID_ACTIVIDAD_EXTERNA as y15_, 
      this_.CANT_ADJUNTOS as y16_, 
      motivocont3_.ADJUNTO as y17_, 
      clasificac5_.ADJUNTO as y18_, 
      this_.ID_ACTIVIDAD_REL as y19_, 
      this_.NUMERO_CONTACTO as y20_, 
      this_.NUMERO_CONTRATO as y21_, 
      this_.ID_FILIAL as y22_, 
      this_.ID_CAP as y23_ 
    from 
      ACTIVIDAD this_ 
      left outer join ESTADO_ACTUAL estadoactu1_ on this_.ID_ACTIVIDAD = estadoactu1_.ID_ACTIVIDAD 
      left outer join ESTADO estado2_ on estadoactu1_.COD_ESTADO = estado2_.COD_ESTADO 
      left outer join MOTIVO_CONTACTO motivocont3_ on this_.COD_MOTIVO_CONTACTO = motivocont3_.COD_MOTIVO 
      left outer join FORMA_CONTACTO formaconta4_ on this_.COD_FORMA_CONTACTO = formaconta4_.COD_FCONTACTO 
      left outer join CLASIFICACION clasificac5_ on this_.COD_CLASIFIC = clasificac5_.COD_CLASIFIC 
    where 
      (
        (
          this_.COD_TSUJETO_SUJ_CONT = ? 
          and this_.CODIGO_WF_SUJ_CONT = ?
        ) 
        or (
          this_.COD_TSUJETO_SUJ_ACT = ? 
          and this_.CODIGO_WF_SUJ_ACT = ?
        ) 
        or (
          this_.COD_TSUJETO_SUJ_CONT = ? 
          and this_.CODIGO_WF_SUJ_CONT = ?
        ) 
        or (
          this_.COD_TSUJETO_SUJ_ACT = ? 
          and this_.CODIGO_WF_SUJ_ACT = ?
        )
      ) 
      and this_.FECHA between ? 
      and ? 
    order by 
      this_.FECHA desc, 
      this_.NUMERO_ACTIVIDAD desc
  ) as temp_ 
where 
  rownumber_ <= ?
```

Por motivos del proyecto estamos migrando como se hacen las consultas a un sistema mas "moderno" ya que el metodo que se usaba antes era poco eficiente.
Hasta ahora vengo copiando bastante bien la respuesta de la consulta hasta que llegue al punto de tener que crear el

```
rownumber() over(
        order by 
          this_.FECHA desc, 
          this_.NUMERO_ACTIVIDAD desc
      ) as rownumber_,
```

me estaba preguntando como podria hacer para crear la consulta con el row number.

El codigo de la query se ve asi:

```
cq.select(cb.construct(PruebaDTO.class,actividad.get("id"),
                        estadoActual.get("estadoString"), motivoContacto.get("description"), actividad.get("fecha"),
                        actividad.get("hora"), estado.get("descripcion"), formaContacto.get("description"),
                        clasificacion.get("description"), actividad.get("usuarioCreador"), actividad.get("nombreSujetoActividad"),
                        actividad.get("idActividadExterna"), actividad.get("numeroActividad"), actividad.get("personaContacto"),
                        actividad.get("nombreSujetoContacto"), actividad.get("numeroContacto"), actividad.get("ani"),
                        actividad.get("cantAdjuntos"), motivoContacto.get("adjunto"),
                        clasificacion.get("aceptaAdjuntos"), actividad.get("idActividadRel"),
                        actividad.get("numeroContrato"), actividad.get("idFilial"),actividad.get("idCap")))
                .where(notNroActividad)
                .where(filtrosAdicionales.toArray(new Predicate[0]))
                .where(holder).orderBy(cb.desc(actividad.get("fecha")), cb.desc(actividad.get("numeroActividad")));
```

cq equivale a criteriaQuery y cb a criteriaBuilder

Quisiera saber como crear un rownumber siguiendo el hilo del codigo que estoy creando actualmente.